# Autohotkey Matrix (AHK)

Tags: autohotkey

At the moment I am working on AI in AHK.

Now I have the problem that I don't know how to deal with a matrix. See below an example matrix:

```
WeightLooper := 1

Loop %NumberOfWeightsLayerTotal%
{
    Random, Weight_%WeightLooper%, -1.0, 1.0
    WeightLooper := WeightLooper + 1 
}

WEIGHTS_1 := Array([Weight_1, Weight_2, Weight_3, Weight_4], [Weight_5, Weight_6, Weight_7, Weight_8], [Weight_9, Weight_10, Weight_11, Weight_12])

TRAINING_INPUTS := []
rows := (LastFilledY - 1)
columns := (LastFilledX - 1)
Xas := 0
Yas := 0
Loop, % rows
{
    Xas := 0
    Yas := Yas + 1
    row := []
    Loop, % columns
    {
        Xas := Xas + 1
        row.push(myarray[Yas][Xas])
    }
    TRAINING_INPUTS.push(row)
}
```

Now I have a matrix of 3x4. Suppose I want a matrix of 10x10, how do I do that? So basically I want to create a variable matrix.

I ask this because my input (csv file) can vary from 2x2 to 1000000x1000000.

Answer (score 4):

I'd probably recommend [pushing](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/objects/Object.htm#Push) a new array into the array in a loop:

```
WEIGHTS_1 := []
rows := 5
columns := 7
Loop, % rows
{
    row := []
    Loop, % columns
    {
        Random, weight, -1.0, 1.0
        row.push(weight)
    }
    WEIGHTS_1.push(row)
}
```

Example output:

```
[[-0.678368,  -0.768605,  -0.274922,   0.049760,  -0.133968,  -0.876030,  -0.235799]
,[-0.296078,   0.359816,  -0.461632,   0.788800,  -0.707147,  -0.200223,  -0.473914]
,[0.474090,    0.085090,   0.458321,  -0.820574,   0.145089,   0.193249,   0.990545]
,[0.205461,    0.901953,  -0.137901,   0.279726,   0.562361,  -0.019861,  -0.887540]
,[0.504811,   -0.876628,  -0.127397,   0.156817,   0.873983,   0.859992,  -0.879222]]
```

Comment: That is a good solution! Thank you.

However, I also want to make the length of the rows variable. Now there are 5 variables. How can I make it 100 automatically?

Sorry but I don't get it.

Comment: For that you can pretty much just do the same as my answer is doing there. Push into a sub-array as many time as is needed. If you can show more of your script, like where the data comes from and in what form the data is, I can show an example of how to do it.

Comment: For this particular example, I am using the following code:





`WeightLooper := 1

Loop %NumberOfWeightsLayerTotal%
{
 Random, Weight_%WeightLooper%, -1.0, 1.0
 WeightLooper := WeightLooper + 1 
}`






To determine the size of my matrix, I would like to use an X value and a Y value.

Suppose I have a matrix that is 5x5. Then I need 25 weights.

However, later in my script I also use data that comes from an Array [?][?]

Comment: Ok, I maybe get what you're trying to do. See my edited answer.

Comment: This is exactly what I need! You are a genius.

Now I have one more question. I would like to extract from an Array [Yas][Xas] values. Please also see original post.

Comment: My mistake... I have some stupid mistakes in that code.

Comment: So is it all good now, or do you still have some trouble?